# pdf print multiple forms with image in access

Tags: ms-access, printing

I have one form in Access, which i use to print the informations from my table, with different date and different images. I want to print all form pages (one row from the table is one page in form) at once, but the problem is that on every page is the same image, the image that is connected to the first row of my table. so the form takes the data for each row (infomation for every row), but for the image takes the first one for every page of the form.
Any solution?

Comment: Exactly how are you 'connecting' image to record?

Comment: I am not familiar with coding just that you know.I am copying the location of the picture in folder
for example:
I:\Pictures\Folder 1\Folder 2\Picture 1.jpg
I:\Pictures\Folder 1\Folder 2\Picture 2.jpg
and so on....
and then I past in the column PICTURES in Access

Comment: Okay, you save image path string into text field in table. Then you have an Image control with ControlSource property set to that field? Don't see why form wouldn't work but better to build a report and print report instead of form.

Comment: sorry my mistake, translating it to eng. is not easy. this is actually a report printed as PDF based on the info. from the tabel. that is right, i save image path string into text field in table, and when i take a look at report in access and read the pages the image also changes. but when i print the report, all pages at once, the PDF file shows for all pages always the same image and always the first one. but when i print each page manually than it shows the right image. i hope that i have explained better.

Comment: How large are images - what are file sizes?

Comment: We are using compressed .jpg, their size are going from 34 -> 164 kb.

Comment: Those should be small enough. I can't see any reason for this issue and since there is no code for analysis, really can't offer solution.

Comment: acctualy this is a FORM, i am working in Germany sorry. the name is FORMULARE in German.

Comment: so there are is no solution?

Comment: Try printing report instead.

Comment: i have saved form as report, but the problem remains. the image that is actually shown in the form stays the same for all pages of the form (report), although in the table are different path string as text entered.

Comment: Sorry, can't replicate issue so cannot determine cause and solution. I have a 442-page report with jpg images over 1,000kb in size. It exports to pdf correctly. Perhaps you should post to a forum that facilitates and encourages attaching files.

Comment: i saw yesterday that the column for image is made as "Long text", does this have an influence?
our form looks similar to this one but with images.
https://www.quackit.com/pix/microsoft_access/microsoft_access_2016/tutorial/add_a_combo_box_to_a_form_in_microsoft_access_1.png

maybe in the properties of the table is something wrong....

is your report made from a table? what are the configurations for the image column?

Comment: how do you print the report? normal print option Adobe PDF or...?

Comment: I found the problem, in the formular was image inserted as unbound object field, now i change it to image and it works. tnx for writing and your time :)

Comment: I did mention Image control in my second comment. I should have thought of OLEObject control could be issue. Glad you figured it out.